# Why would someone create an index on a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

```
db.collection.createIndex()¶
```

> Creates indexes on collections.

I understand why we need indexes on documents, but why on collections?

Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: The same reason you'd add an index to a table in other databases - it can make it more efficient to query a particular column (or in this case, document key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not creating indexes on documents, we index documents on collections, selecting one or more keys. Like you index columns in tables on relational DB world.

Just to find right document (row) from collection (table).

Answer (score 1):

the index creates a part in the storage where the engine can look for entries. The parsing of these entries is really fast. In my case it gives me a performance benefit of aditionally 1000%.

A Find or Aggregate searches through this storage and can find the wanted data without parsing the whole collection.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Do you know how the parsing of these entries works?

Comment: @7Learner You may know it with term "full table scan"